# Target body tag when using ASP.NET Core CSS isolation

Tags: css, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-core-css-isolation

I'm using "CSS isolation" with Razor Pages.

I have a `_Layout.cshtml` and `_Layout.cshtml.css`. I want to apply a background color to the body. So I tried `body { background-color: red }`.

But that generates css with an isolation attribute, e.g. `html body[b-d29f2jaemq] { background-color: red); }`. The `html` and `body` tags don't have such attributes.

Is there a way to target the body tag in a CSS isolation file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But that generates css with an isolation attribute, e.g. `html body[b-d29f2jaemq] { background-color: red); }`. The `html` and `body` tags
> don't have such attributes.
>
> Is there a way to target the body tag in a css isolation file?

I can reproduce this problem, so this might be a bug or by design. I suggest you post this question to the [ASP.NET Core GitHub repository](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues), then the developer team will investigate it.

As a temporary workaround, you can try adding `body { background-color: red }` to the site.css file in the `wwwroot` folder, and add this file reference in the layout page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

Comment: I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41580).

Comment: There is an explanation at that repo issue. Looks like by design.